# How to convert COpaquePointer in swift to some type (CGContext? in particular)

Tags: swift

I have the following code in swift which doesn't compile:

```
class CustomView: NSView {
  override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    var contextPointer: COpaquePointer = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()!.graphicsPort()
    var context: CGContext? = contextPointer as? CGContext
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 0, 0, 1)
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
    CGContextFlush(context)
  }
}
```

How do I convert COpaquePointer to CGContext?

Answer (score 10):

As of Developer Preview 5, `NSGraphicsContext` now has a `CGContext` property. It's not documented yet but it's in the header file:

```
@property (readonly) CGContextRef CGContext NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_10);
```

Answer (score 7):

This is kind of ugly; it would be better if the graphicsPort() method was updated to return a CGContextRef directly (like `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`), rather than a void*. I added this extension to `NSGraphicsContext` to sweep it under the rug for now:

```
extension NSGraphicsContext {
  var cgcontext: CGContext {
    return Unmanaged<CGContext>.fromOpaque(self.graphicsPort()).takeUnretainedValue()
  }
}
```

Just call `NSGraphicsContext.currentContext().cgcontext` anywhere you need a CGContext.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `Unmanaged`, or `fromOpaque`, but this works beautifully! Thanks!

Comment: However, using the `reinterpretCast` sledgehammer seems to work

Comment: What `reinterpretCast`? I typed that into Xcode doc search and got nothing. The new line code would help.

Comment: This works: `return reinterpretCast(self.graphicsPort())`; and here's an [example gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6d1b7ed422debb26b543)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be compiling:

```
var contextPointer = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()!.graphicsPort()
let context = UnsafePointer<CGContext>(contextPointer).memory
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure you need to use .currentContext()! though - isn't the type of currentContext already unwrapped? `class func currentContext() -> NSGraphicsContext!`

Comment: @alaroldai Yes, but I need CGContext not NSGraphicsContext

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016668/how-to-use-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals/24056236#24056236

Answer (score 1):

You are almost near. Try this code

```
class CustomView: NSView {
    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {

        var contextPointer = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()!.graphicsPort()
        var context = UnsafePointer<CGContext>(contextPointer).memory

        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
        CGContextFlush(context)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 6.3 / Swift 1.2, `NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()!.graphicsPort` returns `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` and you can cast it into `CGContextRef` using `unsafeBitCast` because it's just a C pointer. This just reinterpret the pointer value, so should work exactly same with C forced point cast.

```
    let p1  =   NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()!.graphicsPort
    let ctx =   unsafeBitCast(p1, CGContextRef.self)
```

Please take care that such reinterpreting-cast is always very dangerous and used only when you're sure on what you're doing.