# Convert CFContextRef to mutable void pointer in swift?

Tags: pointers, types, casting, swift, void

I'm trying to convert this objc code to swift:

```
CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                proposedRect.size.width,
                                                proposedRect.size.height,
                                                CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                                0,
                                                colorSpaceRef,
                                                (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
NSGraphicsContext *context = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:contextRef flipped:NO];
```

So far I ended up with this:

```
var bitmapContext: CGContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, UInt(proposedRect.width), UInt(proposedRect.height), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image), 0, colorSpace, CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.toRaw()))
let context = NSGraphicsContext(graphicsPort: bitmapContext, flipped: false)
```

The problem is that `CGBitmapContextCreate` returns `CGContext` type and `NSGraphicsContext` initializer accepts `graphicsPort` as `CMutableVoidPointer` type. So how can I convert `CGContext` to `CMutableVoidPointer`?

related reverse type casting found here, but it didn't provide much help to me
[How to convert COpaquePointer in swift to some type (CGContext? in particular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009259/how-to-convert-copaquepointer-in-swift-to-some-type-cgcontext-in-particular)

Comment: Does passing `&contextRef` work?

Comment: it does not. `&contextRef` have `CGContextRef *` type and it's not what I need. Basically I need simple cast `CGContextRef` as `void *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with the `reinterpretCast` function returning intermediate `Int` variable for the `bitmapContext` address.

```
var bitmapContext: CGContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(...)

let bitmapContextAddress: Int = reinterpretCast(bitmapContext)
let bitmapContextPointer: CMutableVoidPointer = COpaquePointer(UnsafePointer<CGContext>(bitmapContextAddress))
let context = NSGraphicsContext(graphicsPort: bitmapContextPointer, flipped: false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think `reinterpretCast` is gone from the language, though; you need to use `unsafeBitCast` instead.

Comment: sure, you are right, but the NSGraphicsContext's object initializer had changed it's signature, so the bit casting is no longer required

Answer (score 0):

The documentation here:https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html

states the following:

> When a function is declared as taking a CMutableVoidPointer argument,
>   it can accept the same operands as CMutablePointer for any type
>   Type.

From that, it should work like this:

```
var p: CMutablePointer<CGContext> = &bitmapContext
NSGraphicsContext *context = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:p flipped:NO];
```

Extended practically, you should be able to pass in `&bitmapContext` directly to a `CMutableVoidPointer` argument.

Swift doesn't have "pointers" in the C sense.

Comment: Original type `CGContextRef` is already a pointer. So in objc I am able to make simple cast `void *pointer = CGBitmapContextCreate(...)` and get what I need. And in swift `&bitmapContext` is pointer to pointer `void **` and it is not exactly what the `NSGraphicsContext` accepts for `graphicsPort` argument

Comment: @chebur This is Swift, not C, not C++, not ObjC. There is no notion of pointers in Swift. If you do not accept or understand that, you will simply not get Swift.

Comment: What you trying to advice is to get pointer to `CGContextRef` by doing `&bitmapContext`. But [Typically graphicsPort is a CGContextRef (opaque type) object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSGraphicsContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSGraphicsContext/graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:flipped:). It means that the function expects exactly the `CGContextRef` value simply downcasted to `CMutableVoidPointer` (`void *` in terms of C), not pointer to `CGContextRef` as you adviced earlier.

Comment: Again, you are thinking in C terms. In Swift, `&` is not a reference operator and the bridging from ObjC to Swift handles passing the opaque type inside. i.e. `&bitmapContext` does **not** create a pointer to `CGContextRef`. There is no such thing as pointers in Swift.

Comment: Swift provides [various types for pointers to enable direct memory access](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_16). There're examples inside to show proper usage of `&`. And so far `&` meaning is to _get a reference to a value_

Comment: Btw, passing `&bitmapContext` leads to crash at runtime, and `reinterpretCast` works fine